RPI: Use a WiFi AP to broadcast the RPI local network
I've been running into some difficulty trying to figure out how to go about the project I would like to do. Here is a flow chart of my approach.
Docker Container > RPI > (via eth0) WiFi AP > Opening the local container via web-browser, probably on a phone.
So far I've set up the docker container on the RPI (v4 w/ 64bit debian OS), and have all of the physical connections set. I am struggling to get the RPI and the AP to communicate. I think what I'm going to need to do is have the RPI host a DHCP server, the AP as a client, and once I am connected to the AP through WiFi I am able to access the local host page, probably on the docker IP of 172.17.0.1. Is there an easier way to approach this? I honestly have never worked with any of these aspects, and have a background in aerospace engineering so this is all completely new.
I have followed this guide with a few modifications due to typos, but cannot get it to work. The eth0 port is up when I connect the RPI to the AP, and I can connect a phone to the AP, but I cannot access the RPI through this.
https://gist.github.com/Konamiman/110adcc485b372f1aff000b4180e2e10
Does anyone have any resources/approach to do this from? I'm also struggling to search in the correct manner to procure results.

What are you actually trying to do? If you just want to run an application in docker and connect to it on your phone, you shouldn't need to mess with creating APs and DHCP servers

Please describe in what way it isn't working. At all?
